# Combine two dataframes

Tags: dataframe, combine

I have two dataframes:
df1 has columns - id, Text, imageid, label
df2 has columns - imageid, imageurl

I want to combine both the dataframes such that the imageurl should be linked to their corresponding imageid in df1.

Can someone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.merge()` to merge dataframes based on a common column:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='imageid',how='left')
df.head()
```